# Mark only 2nd + Duplicates as True and 1st occurrence as False occurrences with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a solution in VBA to mark every duplicate values except the first value in a new column with TRUE or FALSE so that they can be filtered out in a pivot table as a page filter. The first occurrences should be marked as FALSE so the data still shows but sequential values are hidden in the pivot.

```
                .Cells(clclrow, 19) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("C1:C1" & clclrow), .Cells(clclrow, "C")) + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("C1:C1" & clclrow), .Cells(clclrow, "C")) > 2
```

or                 `.Cells(clclrow, 19) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("C1:C1" & clclrow), .Cells(clclrow, "C"))> 1`

where clclrow = 2 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

The attempt still shows all duplicate values as TRUE.

Comment: This is really easy using `=COUNTIFS` and a mixed range reference, no VBA required.

Comment: @BigBen Problem is there is multiple steps not included in the code since this runs off several sub modules and this is a small portion of the code that's needed to be complete. I do know that there's a cells.value Formula method but would rather have it static.

Comment: You can write the formula with VBA, then hard-code its results (also using VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it with this method.

```
temp = (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("C2:C" & clclrow), .Cells(clclrow, "C")) = 1) + 0
                If temp = 0 Then
                    .Cells(clclrow, 16).Value = "TRUE"
                Else
                    .Cells(clclrow, 16).Value = "FALSE"
                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more logic than anything else. I would use a delimiter and assume that every item between the delimiters has duplicates further ahead. Simply select and cut the item, then search/replace the dupes with the matching text plus whatever tag you want to add, and finally paste the cut text back into its original location. Advance beyond the next delimiter and repeat.